# Provisional Enrollment Failed. [MCCloudConfigErrorDomain - 0x80EF (33007)]

Tags: apple-configurator

Trying to provision a brand new iPad with Apple Configurator 2. At some point our company will be deploying 2000 of these iPads, but I get various errors like the one listed in the title.

I have no issues with internet connectivity here. What is causing this error? It happens as soon as the iPad finishes erasing and gets ready to activate.

The profile that I included in the preparation process has the Wifi SSID and password.

Comment: IIRC, this error occurs if the iPad isn't already connected to Wi-Fi.

Comment: It had been connected, I did get this error to stop though. I believe it had something to do with me trying to enroll it in DEP with Configurator 2. I decided to just skip all that, and the error subsided. I decided to just use AC2 to get the device in to supervised mode, apply a "pre" profile,and then use my MDM to do the rest.

Comment: Config 2 is becoming less useful for large scale deployments. Look into JAMF or other robust MDMs. With JAMF, I can prep a slew of iPads with a few key-strokes, once everything is set-up. It links with DEP for enrollment and VPP for apps. Continuing maintenance is a breeze. If you're going to be deploying 2k iPads and other devices, an MDM is the _only_ way to go.

Comment: @IconDaemon, yeah. We actually have VMware's Airwatch MDM which works well. I do have one concern however. If I want to get rid of the settings icon on the screen so no one can get to it, how would users manage their WiFi?

Comment: Good question. We don't hide the settings app - we use whatever restrictions are possible in JAMF configuration profiles to lock down the iPads as best we can. Since 98% of our iPads never leave campus, we've not worried about Wi-Fi changes.

Answer (score 1):

First, try using a wired internet connection or try disabling "Add to Device Enrollment Program"

Enable "Supervised devices"

Answer (score 0):

I had the provisional-enrollment-failed-mccloudconfigerrordomain-0x80ef-33007 error whilst trying to add an iPad Pro and an iPhone 13.

I went through testing Wi-Fi, creating the profile etc as other posters above with no success.

In the end it came down to the internal clock of the device being seriously out of date (months spent in someone's draw I guess).  I put in a SIM card, which allowed the internal clock of the iPad to sync with the Cellular network Time-Servers.

The next time I tried to "Prepare" the device it worked fine.